# Is it possible to make php report errors only to the errorlog?

Tags: php, error-logging

As title describes.

My sites have been moved to a newer environment, and some non-crititcal errors has come up.
I want to suppress all the warnings on the websites, but still want them to be logged to the standard error_log, so i can fix the errors without my sites looking non-functional.

Is there some easy way to do that?

Comment: Turn off `display_errors` in php.ini.  Or in your code `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` Best to _fix_ the errors though.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors  Technically, though, you should fix your code to eliminate the errors/warnings from occurring in the first place.

Comment: yes marc, and im going to, but i want to silence the errors from the websites while i fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
error_log = /var/log/php-scripts.log
display_errors = Off
```

Modify php.ini as shown above.
And restart apache to load the new php.ini

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) for the relevant `php.ini` settings. You will want to pay particular attention to `display_errors`, `log_errors` and `error_log`

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini set (look for the existing entries and change them)

```
display_errors to "0"
```

to disable the output of errors and set

```
log_errors to "1"
```

to enable logging of errors.

You should be able to use [ini_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) as well as [.htaccess](http://davidwalsh.name/php-values-htaccess) to set these values as they are both marked as INI_ALL if you don't have access to php.ini